# How to print a sorted list from an external text document on Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, external

I'm doing my GCSE computer science programming project, and wondered if I could get some help. I have code that prints out the scores of different players in a  dice game on an external document, and what Player achieved it:

```
total1 = str(total1)
total2 = str(total2)
if total2 > total1:
    file = open("winners.txt", "a")
    winner = "Player2"
    file.write("\n" + winner + ", " + total2)

if total1 > total2:
    file = open("winners.txt", "a")
    winner = "Player1"
    file.write("\n" + winner + ", " + total1)
```

Yet the project asks to sort this list and put the sorted list (only displaying the top five scores) in an external text document. I've got this code:

```
FileName = ("winners.txt")
data=(FileName).readLines()
sortedlist = data.sort()
file = open("top scores.txt", "a+")
file.write("The top scores are: " + "\n")
file.write(sortedlist[0])
file.write(sortedlist[1])
file.write(sortedlist[2])
file.write(sortedlist[3])
file.write(sortedlist[4])
```

But i'm not sure where to go from here. Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show an example input file?

Comment: ...smells like homework.

Answer (score 0):

This will write the top 5 scores only to your text file:

```
sortedlist = data.sort()
with open("top scores.txt", "a+") as ts:
    ts.write("The top scorers are: ")
    for score in sortedlist[:5]:
        ts.write(score)
```

Comment: It seems though that the lines in the winner files are written with the player name followed by the score.  So wouldn't `sortedlist` end up being sorted by player name, not score?

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Note that if every line of winners.txt begins with the player's name, not the score, then sorting the list is going to sort by player name, not score. But if you have a list of strings in the form of "player_name, score", you could do this to make a list of the scores sorted by highest to lowest score:

```
>>> scores = ['Player1, 80', 'Player1, 90', 'Player2, 70', 'Player2, 100']
>>> splitscores = [s.split(', ') for s in scores]
>>> numscores = [ (int(s[1]), s[0]) for s in splitscores ]
>>> numscores.sort(reverse=True)
>>> numscores
[(100, 'Player2'), (90, 'Player1'), (80, 'Player1'), (70, 'Player2')]
```

Using this approach, you should be able to get all of the scores into a list and then get the score values and winner names of the top 5 scores.

By the way, you may want to include some `file.close()` statements in your code to finish those `open()` commands.